# Add string to inline CSS with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add the IE hack for `background-size: cover` to a dynamically created background image.
I must add thisto my elements inline css:

```
<div style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + imgsrc + "', sizingMethod='scale');">
```

I have tried:

```
var iehackstring = "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + imgsrc + "', sizingMethod='scale');";

$(this).css(iehackstring);
```

and:

```
var iehackstring = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + imgsrc + "', sizingMethod='scale');";

$(this).css("filter" : iehackstring);
```

But cannot get it to work.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Why not just put this in a CSS file and wrap it in the IE conditional?

Comment: @Justin is right. Just put it in a CSS file and add a class to your target

Comment: $('head').append($("<style></style>").text(iehackstring))

Comment: you can also do $(".something").attr("style", "your new style");

Comment: @JustinWood but the image src still needs to be a variable. Can this be done that way?

Comment: If you throw it between `<style></style>` tags it can be.

Comment: @AndréPena this is a good idea and I have tried it but it overwrites the existing inline styles I have

Comment: Will this work? `$(this).css("filter", iehackstring);`

Comment: @dandavis suggestion is the best

Comment: You can also use `addClass()` like `$(this).addClass('forIe');` but first you must create the css class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that elegant, but you could try this:

```
$(this).attr("data-original-style", $(this).attr("style"));
$(this).attr("style", $(this).attr("style") + "[your new style comes here"]);
```

Just in case you need the original again.. you can just get it from `attr("data-original-style")` and set it in `style` again.